# React app production build still too large even after removing node_modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules, babeljs, create-react-app

I am working to remove unneeded libraries from my React app that was originally bootstrapped using `create-react-app`. My `node_modules` folder had 500 MB worth of dependencies. I removed several and got the number down to around 300 MB. My `src` folder with my code is only a few KB large.

With 500 MB in `node_modules`, my production build `bundle.js` file was coming out at 4 MB. I thought by removing almost 50% of `node_modules`, the bundle size would be a lot smaller. But it's actually still at 4 MB.  The built project has correct config (e.g. `package.json` does not list the removed libraries, nor does my `yarn.lock` file, so it truly seems like they are not there).

How could this make sense?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: the `bundle.js` file size didn't change because you removed **unused** dependencies that weren't bundled in the first place

Comment: did you use chunk?

Comment: there is some analyze tools for check which module cause huge bundle.js